# Dwarfism in a 9 foot tall humanoid race

Tags: xenobiology, mythical-creatures

My story has a race exactly like humans, except they grow to be on average 9 feet tall. One of characters belongs to this race, but she is considered a dwarf to her people. This causes her to live with humans without much issue. She doesn’t stand out; if anything they think she is a human.

Now my question is, would this be possible?

Comment: Welcome MANIAC, this is much too broad and undefined to fit in with the rules on our site. You know that there's more than one type of dwarfism right? CHH dwarfism and pituitary to start with, could you be much more specific about what it is that you're asking? Please take the tour: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour and read up in our help centre about how to ask a question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit  your question to fit in with our rules: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/138468/edit

Comment: Hey MANIAC... please add in way more information.... Are you asking about how tall a human could possible grow? or is this some mixed race of humans and 9 foot dwarves? Please make sure that everything we need is written down.

Comment: @Shadowzee Just fixed it.

Comment: @MANIAC What you seem to be asking is if your people could have an opinion about one of their population, is that right? How is this not opinion based and too broad to answer and how can we know what it is that you're asking? Please read my previous comment.

Comment: @Fay Suggers I wasn’t asking for the opinion of humans. I’m asking if it’s possible for the condition to make her the same height of humans.

Comment: @MANIAC What "condition" are you refering to, you say dwarfism, what type, what is the condition of your race, what kind of gravity-well do they live in, what is the range of parameters of your question? You say she doesn't stand out, then what is the question exactly? People need to know what would constitute a good answer.

Comment: You might instead consider simply going for some form of late onset growth hormone deficiency (or early switch off of same), it's a hormone released by the pituitary (base of the brain) so you might even be able to hand wave it as caused by a blow to the head when she was 7 (or whatever your giants equivalent of 7 is), you'd have to ask someone that knows if that's really plausible or not, because I don't.

Comment: .After much research, I think I found my answer. I tried to fit in a condition to it, but humans have short people. I don't know if this is backed by anything but I found [this](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/midget?s=t).

Comment: @Pelinore It's a fantasy but didn't want to go the route of its magic, but judging by responses its looking like its heading there.

Comment: A mild [growth hormone deficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarfism) is maybe the "clinical" cause of reduced height with the least effect on proportions (that looks most "normal" just smaller) but there's a **lot** of natural variation in peoples height anyway, throw in a restricted diet during childhood (one reason people used to be shorter than now on average), you might mix those up & just say "that's just how she is, smaller than all her brethren".

Comment: @Pelinore Thanks, just found a great backstory.

Answer (score 3):

In my other answer, I described how dwafism would not be viable, Here is something that possibly COULD work.

Rather than dwarfism, there is another route to go:  Stunted growth creating a midget, instead of a dwarf.

Your giants begin strongly resembling humans through their youth.  Only after they get over two meters do their bones start to thicken, their hands and feet grow and their growth outward begins to match their growth upward. This would make a kind of sense, as your race of giants evolved to have their children appear to be human, and thus not hunted down and killed, as it would be a form of camouflage

Your hero due to some disease (or curse) is trapped in what is a child's body for her race.  Since she is in that child's body, she blends in with the resto of the humans.

You may want to make it a bit more interesting by giving her some trait that would make her recognizable to her people, be it markings on her skin, the shape of her ears, or something else that is subtle, but her people would know to look for.

Answer (score 1):

No, 9 foot tall giants are incompatible with our physiques which is why extremely tall people have multiple health problems. To have people that tall would mean multiple changes to our structure resulting in humanoids that look distinctly different.

She may be able to live amongst humans, but not unnoticed. At best she would be considered extremely unfortunate in regards to her looks, or deformed.

Answer (score 1):

A gigantic race would have to have thicker, and wider bones, be much stockier with larger lung capacity, and significantly wider.

A dwarf of that race would look like Andre the Giant compressed down to 2 meters, with hands the size of a gorilla, shoes somewhere around size 26-27, and bones like tree trunks, and a massive head.  She would look more like a beast than a normal human.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is probably **no**, unless you "hand-wave" the actual cause like you hand-wave the existence of the giants themselves.

Hypopituitarism is "almost certainly" the only type of dwarfism that would get you close to what you're describing.  There may be some other, extraordinarily rare, types that come closer, but it's certainly the most common type that comes anywhere close.

All other (relatively common) types of dwarfism would cause other side effects that would make her distinctly not a 'normal' adult human, such as impaired mental capacity and delayed physical maturity (in other words, she'd look and act like an absurdly tall child, not passable as adult, even if the height, alone, were not an issue).

In humans, an average female is about 5 foot 3 inches (it varies from place to place, and with accuracy of measurement, etc., but this number should be close enough to accurate to make my point).  The average human female with Hypopituitarism is 4 foot 3 inches.  If you scale up that difference, and an average giant is 9 feet, then a giant with Hypopituitarism would average about 7 foot 2 inches.  While I'm sure there are normal human females in that height range, they are the exceptions, not the rule, and your giant would definitely "stand out" in any crowd, just like those exceptionally tall human females do.

If you do the math in the other direction, and assume that this "dwarf giant" is average human female height of 5 foot 3 inches, and then scale up to normal height for your giant, the average giant female would be only about 6 foot 6 inches tall.  In those ranges, any giant on the shorter end of normal could pass for a normal human on the taller end of normal, so a dwarf giant being able to mix in with humans wouldn't be anything really exceptional, she'd just be able to do it better than most other giants

So:

1. Either this condition she has is absurdly rare,
2. or it doesn't correlate to any known human condition at all and is a specific issue among the giants themselves,
3. or it just plain won't work at all

Handwave the cause, and don't base it on humans, if you're going to do it.  If giants exist, their own unique form of dwarfism could also exist.

Comment: Elephants suffer from dwarfism as well https://news.mongabay.com/2013/12/little-elephant-is-the-first-scientific-record-of-dwarfism-in-the-wild/

Comment: @Borgh  That's a very interesting article, thanks.  It's worth noting that the elephant was not proportionately smaller than a normal elephant.  Instead, it has a relatively correctly sized body with shorter than normal legs.  This particular type of dwarfism would not lend itself well to the OP's requirements, but it is a good example of my very last point, that the giants will need their own form of dwarfism (like this elephant has it's own form) for the OP's scenario to work, since a human-type dwarfism just won't fit.

Comment: Actually the most common form of human dwarfism, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achondroplasia usually means relatively short limbs with a more normal torso and regular head.

Comment: @Borgh  I know, but since disproportionate solutions were originally ruled out by the requirements of the question, it was not presented as a possible solution.  And that is exactly what my comment about "other side effects" in the third paragraph indicates, as it rules out those forms of dwarfism

Answer (score 0):

We're going to need some more information to properly answer this, but, as a general statement goes, pretty tall- the tallest human, Robert Wadlow, was 8'11.1". I would keep in mind that most humans that grow incredibly tall often suffer from heart problems, and die at a fairly young age. Wadlow died at age 22, for instance. Thus, this race would likely need a larger, more powerful heart and reinforced bones.

Overall, I would hazard a maximum height of 13'-16' before major circulatory problems arise. Keep in mind that this is a ballpark guess, and with a little hand waving and evolutionary explanation, this could be extended to a much greater height.

Comment: just added some info.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for her to live as a Human, however she will likely be outcast a little as well due to her enormous size. She is roughly 2.7m which is way to high for normal houses. Her clothes and shoes will also be too large for normal sizes and will require them to be custom made. Any conventional vehicle she gets into will be far too small to sit or stand in.

It is also possible for her to use this difference to rise to fame, but it will really depend on you the Creator of this scenario.

For a quick comparison, the tallest man on earth 8'11. The current tallest man is roughly 8'3. Hagrid from harry potter is 8'6  and those blue Avatar people were 10'.

Comment: _"She is roughly 2.7m which is way to high for normal houses"_ that's 8.85 feet tall, the OP said the race grows to 9 feet, but he also said this is a dwarf among them, & given the questions title I presume he means that literally & she has actual dwarfism, so 4.5 feet tall is more likely closer to the mark of what he's thinking of for her.

Comment: I was thinking a little taller. My thinking was if dwarfism in humans is 4 feet 1 inch and lower, and the average height of a female human is around 5.5-5.7 feet. Then for a race that has an average of 9 feet for female it would be around 6ish feet

Comment: @Pelinore I guess I interpreted it wrong. My bad.... wouldn't they just be like the short people we have now......now I'm confused about the question...

Comment: @MANIAC : If you're using dwarfism in humans as your model there's a lot of variation depending on the exact type but mostly types have disproportionately short limbs with the head generally the same size as a normal full grown adult (I'm not sure about the torso) so she's going to be the right height for a normal human perhaps but oddly proportioned & have a _very_ large head.

Comment: @Shadowzee : I _think_ he's asking if it's plausible that a female giant with some sort of dwarfism could pass for human? but don't quote me on that, because I'm not sure :)

Comment: @Pelinore yeah the more I researched it, the more it didn’t fit the way I’m progressing my story. My protagonist is her son and has a human father, but I haven’t checked the effects on childbirth with dwarfism. Your last comment to Shadowzee is exactly what I’m asking.

Comment: @MANIAC If you would like to keep looking for answers, update the question with the relevant information from all these comments. Sometimes discussion is what we need to figure out the question you are actually trying to ask.

Comment: @Shadowzee I don't think there's much to ask after that. She's just short. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Human dwarfs are anyone 4'10" and under regardless of the sex. The average US height is 5'6". That is 88% of the average height, which is 7'11" for your fictional race. The shortest human ever was 1'9.5", the giant equivalent of this would be 2'11", so dwarfs of your species should range from 2'11" to 7'11".